# How would one model an Ork Warboss with a Kombi-Skorcha?

Tags: warhammer-40k, modelling

The current Ork Codex states that an Ork Warboss "is armed with a kombi-weapon with rokkit launcher". However, it also states

> This model may replace its kombi-weapon with rokkit launcha with a weapon from the Shooty Weapons list.

This implies that I can arm my Warboss with a Kombi-Skorcha instead of a Kombi-Weapon with Rokkit Launcha. However, the sprue only came with a Rokkit Launcha, not a Kombi-Skorcha for the Warboss. The sprue *does* include a Kombi-Skorcha, but it is intended for a regular Nob, meaning the part doesn't fit.

What are my options here? Do I need to buy a different part that would fit? Do I have to make one myself? Or am I completely out-of-luck and just need to say "By the way, my Warboss has a Kombi-Skorcha" every time I play?

Comment: Sorry I can't provide a proper answer to this. It seems there aren't any Ork players around here! All I can say is that many GW character kits lack one or more of the weapon options found in the rules. In your case the best option may be to do a quick hand swap between the Nob arm and the Warboss one.

Comment: @LesserKhan I already conducted a conversion, and added instructions down below as to how I did it. Pictures will be added once available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there are no pre-made "Ork Warboss Arm with Kombi-Skorcha" bits, I have decided to do a conversion myself. I will outline the steps I have taken below.

1. Cut both the Ork Warboss Arm with the Kombi-Rokkit Launcha and a Kombi-Skorcha for Ork Nobs from the sprue and remove any excess plastic and mold lines.
2. Cut off the front of the Rokkit Launcha, so that the magazine still remains. This way, you can prevent accidental damage to the Warboss Arm.
3. Cut off the right arm of the Ork nob, so that the hand is still attached to the grip of the Kombi-Skorcha.
4. Remove parts of the right hand, bit by bit, until only the index finger remains (until about to the knuckle), and the bottom tank of the Skorcha (below the hand). It's recommended to use a small saw to cut through the hand once thin enough, then use the hobby knife to remove the remains of the hand bit by bit.
5. On the side of the Warboss Arm, remove the remains of the Kombi-Rokkit Launcha bit by bit, until only the hand and the stock above the hand remains.
6. Cut away the part in front of the "bow" in the stock. It's best to hold the Skorcha in front of the Rokkit Launcha, to ensure not too much is cut away.
7. Cut part of the Warboss' index finger away. This will be replaced by the index finger still attached to the Kombi-Skorcha.
8. In order to put the index finger into the proper place, either part of the bottom of the Kombi-Skorcha's stock need to be cut out, or part of the hand of the Warboss need to be removed to create a "slot" in which the weapon slides into. Do either one of these things. I decided to cut part of the hand out.
9. Once everything is in place, the top of the Skorcha should be a little bit below the old shoulder stock of the Kombi-Rokkit-Launcher. You can either leave it like this to create a "thrown-together-from-parts"-look, sand down the stock or add some greenstuff for a better transition between the shoulder stock and the rest of the gun.
10. The tank down below will be a little too high to fit below the hand of the Warboss. *Carefully* bend the plastic down a little bit, so that the tank fits below the hand.
11. Glue the new Skorcha to the hand and ensure that the stock aligns with the barrel (unless you want the weapon to look slightly bent). Give the glue about an hour to dry enough.
12. Once the glue is dry, glue the bottom tank to the hand. You can either leave the old grip there and attach the tank to that, or cut the old grip away and attach the tank directly to the bottom of the tank.
13. Once everything has dried, you can begin to remove the remains of the left Nob hand, still holding the front of the Skorcha. To do this, you can either use a hobby knife to cut the hand away layer by layer, or use a rotary tool to sand the remains away.
14. Optionally, you can attach some leftover bits from other models (spikes, glyphs, etc.) to cover up the remains of the hand. Such bits can also be bought individually, for several cents per piece.

It should be advised that these instructions worked for *me*, they don't necessarily need to work for you. It depends on the standards that you set for your models. For example, the index finger looks a bit off, since the angle at which a Nob holds their weapon is different than the angle at which a Warboss holds their weapon. If it must absolutely be perfect, please be prepared to add some greenstuff to relevant parts to ensure the models match your expectations.

---

Here are some pictures, showing the final result:

[image: Picture of the Ork Warboss Arm from the Front]

[image: Picture of the Ork Warboss Arm from the Back]

Comment: I will add pictures of the finished conversion once I'm able.

Comment: Very detailed instructions! Thanks for sharing them.

Comment: @LesserKhan I tried to be as detailed as possible, but I couldn't add a true step-by-step guide (e.g. now file 1.25mm from the hand away), because it was my first conversion and just used my best judgement.

Answer (score 0):

MeckMK1 already gave a beautiful answer on how to modify your Warboss with included parts to model it with the skorcha, but you do have other options. While your Warboss kit did include a skorcha (even if with the wrong arm attached), it's not uncommon to have models that can take weapons that aren't at all included in the set (the Tau Crisis Suits are popularly equipped with 3 Cyclic Ion Blasters each, yet only the Commander set includes that weapon, and only one of them at that!). So when you don't have a proper included equipment choice, here are the usual options:

- **Get the weapon from another kit** - Find the piece you need from another set's sprue and attach/modify it to your model. Should always be tournament legal.
- **Modify an included weapon** - Take whatever current weapon you have and get your hobby knife, green stuff, and extra plastic to chop something together that looks similar to the represented weapon. May take a bit of artistic talent for a clean result. I believe this is generally be tournament legal.
- **Buy third party pieces** - There are a number of third party vendors that make their own casts of individual pieces, so if your kit comes with one copy of a weapon you'd like to run 2 of, this can be a simpler option than trying to kitbash your own. Note that using third party bits on your models is discouraged by Games Workshop and may not be welcome at official tournaments.
- **Proxy the weapons** - When all else fails, if you're playing a friendly game and your models are easy enough to differentiate, just say that you're running your Warboss with the skorchas. Obviously not an option in WYSIWYG games though.

Comment: Proxying is surely the easiest, but if your warboss is the warlord of your army, then it may be worth the time and money spent to convert.